# Starting an activity in another class in android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-intent

I'm exploring and learning how to program the android phone and right now I have 2 classes (MainActivity and SubActivity and 2 layouts (main and subactivity).

In MainActivity, I have a button, when I click on the button, i want to show th subactivity layout and execute the SubActivity activity so that I can click on the the button there and return to the MainActivity.

The following is the code for MainActivity

```
package com.test.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnSubActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCallSubActivity);
    btnSubActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SubActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

The following is the code in SubActivity

```
package com.test.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SubActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subactivity);


}
```

}

The following is the layout of main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:text="Call Sub Activity" 
    android:id="@+id/btnCallSubActivity" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
```

The following is the layout of SubActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Call Main Activity" 
        android:id="@+id/btnCallMainActivity" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I get a runtime error when I click on the button on main layout. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: what is your error? Show the stacktrace from the logcat.

Comment: Is the subactivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml? Also, can you give details of what the "runtime error" is? Have you tried the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing     `android:orientation="vertical"` in your second linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide logs. But before check if you have forgotten to add SubActivity to `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SubActivity" android:label="Some label"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out that I was missing <activity android:name=".SubActivity" android:label="Some label"/>
in the Android Manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.Android.SubActivity");
StartActivity(i);
```

//Inside the quotes write out the path of the package. Hope this helps